# azure http trigger works fine locally, loads fine on cloud, throws error when given params

Tags: azure, http, azure-functions

This should be an easy thing:

I have this http trigger:

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("httphook")]
        // def link: localhost:7070/api/httphook?function=webhook&data=this_could_be_your_data
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
     
            string function = req.Query["function"];
     
            if (function == "webhook")
            {
                // do the webhook
                string data = req.Query["data"];
                return new OkObjectResult("ja");
     
            }
            else
            {
                return new OkObjectResult("error");
            }
   
        }
   
    }
```

When I run it locally and open this linK:

localhost:7070/api/httphook?function=webhook

I am being returned "ja".

Now I use VS to upload this to azure (all settings are default, and all is set up from the gui in vs)

and the page loads here:

https://webhookcircles.azurewebsites.net

When you click the link, youll easily see that the page says "it works fine".

Now giving it the final link

```
https://webhookcircles.azurewebsites.net/api/httphook?function=webhook
```

It returns: 401 page doenst work.

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After publishing your function to azure, you need to use the function key in order to access the URL, as you are using  `AuthorizationLevel.Function`

You can copy the URL as shown below

[image]

or you can get the function key from below

[image]

Now your URL will look like

```
https://webhookcircles.azurewebsites.net/api/httphook?code=<function key here>&function=webhook
```

**`Output:`**

[image]